# Handling Onload events to add server side logic in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to know how do we handle onload event so that we add some business logic once a view is loaded. 
In brief this is what i want to achieve - 
   I have a entity object which i am showing as editable ADF table. Now once the page is loaded and I want the table to show at least 4 rows no matter how many rows exist in Database table. For example, if database table has 2 entries then ADF table should show those 2 rows and additional blank 2 rows in ADF table. And if the database table has 6 rows it should show 6 rows in ADF table.
How to programmatically handle this functionality. What functions and methods i need to override or add.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, including doing this in a method call in the taskflow before you reach the page.
Some options:
https://blogs.oracle.com/adf/entry/an_epic_question_how_to